# Why am I getting this parenthesis error in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to initiate a module in a top level in Verilog (beginner).
Here is the top Level code:

```
module top(

//////////// SEG7 //////////
output           [7:0]      HEX0,
output           [7:0]      HEX1,
output           [7:0]      HEX2,
output           [7:0]      HEX3,
output           [7:0]      HEX4,
output           [7:0]      HEX5,

//////////// LED //////////
output           [9:0]      LEDR,

//////////// SW //////////
input            [1:0]      SW);
always@(SW) begin



testgen test(.select[1](SW[1]), .select[0](SW[0]), data0[3:0], data1    [3:0], data2[3:0], data2[3:0]);



end

endmodule
```

Here is testgen (the module I'm trying to initiate

```
module testgen (
input      [1:0] select,
output reg [3:0] data0,
output reg [3:0] data1,
output reg [3:0] data2,
output reg [3:0] data3
);

always @(*) begin
  case (select)
     2'b00: begin
        data0 = 4'b0011;    // 3
        data1 = 4'b0010;    // 2
        data2 = 4'b0001;    // 1
        data3 = 4'b0000;    // 0
     end
     2'b01: begin
        data0 = 4'b1010;    // A
        data1 = 4'b1100;    // C
        data2 = 4'b1110;    // E
        data3 = 4'b1111;    // F
     end
     2'b10: begin
        data0 = 4'b0111;    // 7
        data1 = 4'b0001;    // 1
        data2 = 4'b0000;    // 0
        data3 = 4'b1010;    // A
     end
     2'b11: begin
        data0 = 4'b0101;    // 5
        data1 = 4'b1111;    // F
        data2 = 4'b1100;    // C
        data3 = 4'b0010;    // 2
     end
     default: begin
        data0 = 4'b0000;    // 0 should never be selected
        data1 = 4'b0000;    // 0 should never be selected
        data2 = 4'b0000;    // 0 should never be selected
        data3 = 4'b0000;    // 0 should never be selected
     end
  endcase
end

endmodule
```

There's a bunch of other modules I want to incorporate in the top level, but I just want to know why I'm getting the following error

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at top.v(29) near text: "[";    expecting "(".
```

Am I instantiating incorrectly? Why is this happening? Line 29 is the line where I instantiate testgen. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There two major issues with your code that I can see. First is you are instantiating a module in an `always` block. Modules should always be instantiated on a "top" level, ie not in a procedural block like `always` or `assign` but just in a module's body. Remember, modules are not functions and are not called like functions but instantiated. Second, you cannot assign ports using the `.port[index](var)` syntax, you need to assign an entire port to a single variable. To do what you are trying to do, you should just pass in your `SW` variable to your `select` port of `testgen` like so (also, use that explicit assignment for all variables):

```
testgen test(.select(SW), // Just connect these directly, will connect SW[0] to select[0], SW[1] to select[1]
             .data0(data0), // Use .port explicit connection for all variables
             .data1(data1), // Minor issue, the code you provided doesnt define data0-data2 in the top module, be careful of implicit declaration
             .data2(data2), // Use "`default_nettype none" to avoid these issues
             .data3(data2)); // You use data2 here and not data3, its unclear if that was intentional
```